# List comprehension of zero length

Tags: python, list

I'm generating a random list of 100 numbers that can be 1 up to 20.
I'm generating the list using list comprehension methods like the following code suggests.

I have created a first function in which i basically create the list. The list is created as expected!

```
import random


v = []

def generate_v():
  v = [random.randint(0,100) for i in range(0,100)]
  return v
print(generate_v())


def avg_v():
  return sum(v)/len(v)
print(avg(v))
```

But if i do another function in which i need the length of my generated list it keeps my giving errors saying i can't divide by zero. Basically it is assuming my created list has no length whatsoever

Answer (score 4):

`print(generate_v())` calls the function, prints its result and *discards that result*. The `v` inside the function has nothing to do with the `v` outside.

A better approach would be

```
import random

def generate_v():
  v = [random.randint(0,100) for i in range(0,100)]
  return v

def sum_v(v):
  return sum(v)/len(v)

# now the code:
v = generate_v()
print(v)
print(sum(v))
print(sum_v(v))
```

Comment: I prefer this answer as it avoids global variables which there is no requirement for in the OP. I think the asker just hasn't understood scope and variable passing; this points them toward normal practice.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're creating a variable `v` inside the `generate_v` function without telling python that it's global (using `global v`, which I don't recommend), it is considered local and has no relation with the `v` outside of it (and thus is not modifying it), so, what you can do is assign the list returned by `generate_v` to the global variable `v`:

```
def generate_v():
  return [random.randint(0,100) for i in range(0,100)]

v = generate_v()
```

Test:

```
import random

def generate_v():
  return [random.randint(0,100) for i in range(0,100)]

def sum_v():
  return sum(v) / len(v)

v = generate_v()

print(sum(v))
```

Output (random):

```
5411
```

Comment: OP is possibly confused about how functions work generally, so your answer might be more useful if you move all the module level code together at the end.

Answer (score 1):

One simplest solution is to match the `v` outside with the one inside the `generate`.

```py
v = []

def generate_v():
  global v # Add this
  v = [random.randint(0,100) for i in range(0,100)]
  return v
```

That way, python does not create new variable called `v`.